# How to ignore regular expression results if previous character is / (basically ignore link href content)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following text:

```
<a href="/test-string">test-string</a>
```

And i want to write a regular expression that will catch all "test-string" that will appear in the whole document (i am scanning all h and p tags) but will only treat those that are not followed by a "/", or basically ignore the "/test-string" in the link href and only return the link text, as else it will break my links. (as i want to grab that to wrap it to another element).

At the moment i have this:

```
/test-string(?!\/)/g
```

link to the RegExpr to test/see:

http://www.regexr.com/3brf5

Where is the error? The negative look ahead should take care of this?

Comment: I think you are checking for `/` at the wrong position. Try `/[^\/]\btest-string(?![^<]*>)/g`.

Comment: Since lookahead looks ahead of your string you can't use it for looking behind. There is a lookbehind mechanism, but AFAIK it's not available in JS: you can see how it works in PCRE (PHP regex mechanism) here: https://regex101.com/r/gE6kS3/1

Comment: Also, can you explain a bit more what do you want to be matched? Only `test-string` that's inside the tag (between `<` and `>`)? Or the `test-string` after the `/` sign, but not the sign itself? Or maybe both?

Comment: Only the text should be matched, as i want to wrap it in a span to add some styles, wherever it appears. If the matched returned includes the same text in the href in the link tag, the link will be wrapped as well, resulting in wrong html code.

Comment: @stribizhev, your code seems to work, however it is looking for the < character to start with, which is not right. It will also include the < character? I updated the RegExp example to reflect this

Comment: Yes, it will return a match with a first character other than `/` as **there is no look-behind in JS**. Are you replacing or just capturing? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I need to capture all instanced of "test-string", in any place other than in a link's href. I need then to wrap it in something, which i am doing in jquery just fine so far. My only problem is that all reg exp i used cannot really do just that, but capture more (just like the < character or the whole text in href as well). Does it make sense? Maybe there is a way to keep a really simple selection code but ignore anything in a href?

Comment: Ok, have a look at [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/sK5iT5/1). And perhaps, you know of [Autolinker.js](https://github.com/gregjacobs/Autolinker.js/)? Depending on what you are really doing, it can be a much better approach.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly and you want only link text (eg. `<a ...>`**test-string**`</a>` the bold text), then you can search for `>` and `<` characters and capture what's inside.

See here: [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/sJ6fH5/2)
This allows for any characters inside: [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sJ6fH5/3)

EDIT: I have updated the groups to not capture `>` and `<` characters, now the only thing captured is the text within the tag.

This might need some tweaking, if it doesn't match all your cases correctly please tell so and I'll try to fix this.